# Release method not recognized at runtime (non Cocoa)

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I'm a newbie to Objective-C but have extensive experience in C and C++.  The first thing I have noticed is that there is a real void in basic tutorials out there as all assume you are developing for the iPhone or Mac and using Cocoa.  I'm not using Cocoa or Gnustep.  To the point:

As a simple example to get started I'm trying to wrap the C's File I/O functionality.  My code starts as 
File.h

```
#include <objc/Object.h>
#include <stdio.h>
@interface File:Object
{
    FILE *pFile;
    char *path;
}

@property FILE *pFile;
@property char *path;

- (void)new;
- (void)OpenReadText:(const char*)var1;
- (void)release;

@end
```

And File.m

```
#include "File.h"

@implementation File

@synthesize pFile, path;

- (void)new
{
    self = [super init];
}
- (void)release
{
    fclose(pFile);
    [super release];
}

- (void)OpenReadText:(char*)var1
{
    path = var1;
    pFile = fopen(path,"r");
}

@end
```

Then main.m

```
#include <stdio.h>
#import <objc/Object.h>
#include "File.h"

int main(void) {

File *Fileobj = [File new];

[Fileobj OpenReadText:"File.h"];

[Fileobj release];


}
```

The compiler gives me a warning that my object "may not respond to '-release'".  Then when running the program is results in a runtime error: "does not recognize release.  This application has requested the Runtime to terminate" .. and so on.

I'm guessing I'm making a simple newbie error, but where?  Or perhaps there is something missing?  I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction here.  Thanks.

If this qst has been asked already then a reference would do too.  I did try to find a reference but no luck.

FOLLOW UP:

changed release method to

```
- (void)release
{
    fclose(pFile);
    [super free];
}
```

and it appeared to work.  Apparently `free` is recognized in `object.h`.

Comment: what platform/compiler are you using? is Foundation framework available to you? `release` is a method in `NSObject` so you have to subclass from it. also one mistake, `new` should have return type of `id`. you should know that `void` means no return value.

Comment: No I am not using the foundation framework.  I thought `release` was not a standard method, but it was hard to tell since every tutorial is based around the foundation framework.  The `new` method works though.  This makes me think there must be an equivalent de-allocation method in object.h

Comment: FWIW, there is a dearth of ObjC tutorials outside of the Cocoa environments (and to some extent Gnustep) because anything else is basically academic. I'm sure there exist such environments, but without at least the Foundation framework, you're doing a lot of lifting from scratch. Certainly a cool project, and useful to get the underpinnings, but no tutorials because almost no one does it. (Also, ObjC is unusual in that there isn't an ISO/ANSI/ECMA standard around it.)

Comment: @BenZotto +1 for the info on there being no ISO/ANSI/ECMA standard.

Comment: If you're compiling objc for windows/linux, Apple's CoreFoundation is open source and compiles to both platforms.

Comment: Why the heck are you using `Object`? That's ancient. Use `NSObject` as your base class instead.

Comment: @JackLawrence `CoreFoundation` is a C library which provides similar functionality to `Foundation`,  `Foundation` is the Objective-C library.  Apple's `Foundation` is not, to my knowledge, open source. There are some open source implementations; GNUstep, Cocotron and PureFoundation for example.

Comment: @mttrb that's the point. I'm assuming he can't use cocoa/foundation because he's compiling for a different OS. I was just giving him an FYI that he doesn't have to start with plain C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @xlc0212 pointed out, the reference counting style of memory management is included in NSObject.

NSObject is a part of CoreFoundation library for Cocoa, CocoaTouch and GnuStep. I would say you need to link to CoreFoundation.

One book that I've read and focuses on pure Objective-C (not necessarily Cocoa) is "Programming in Objective-C 2.0" by Steven G Kochan.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to download the CoreFoundation.  Just familiarizing myself with the bare minimal at the moment.

Comment: Just added some details to my answer - a book. . Tried it a few years ago when I was learning Objective-C on Linux. . . . please vote if you found the answer helpful.

Comment: I think you mean `NSObject` is a part of **`Foundation`**, not `CoreFoundation`. (`CoreFoundation` is roughly the procedural C-based equivalent to `Foundation`....

Comment: Take a look at the answer by @mttrb - really nice.

Answer (score 4):

As others have said it is unusual to use Objective-C without the Foundation frameworks.  However, the `Object` class should implement `release`, `retain` etc.  The `Object` class included (but not used) in Apple's Objective-C Runtime certainly contains these basic methods.

Assuming your `Object` class does contain these basic methods there are a couple of problems with your class as implemented.

First, you have created a `new` instance method which simply calls `[super init]`.  The `new` method by convention is a class method which is shorthand for calling `alloc` and `init` to create and initialise an object.  `new` is defined in Apple's `Object` class.  It is implemented as:

```
+ (id)new
{
        id newObject = (*_alloc)((Class)self, 0);
        Class metaClass = self->isa;
        if (class_getVersion(metaClass) > 1)
            return [newObject init];
        else
            return newObject;
}
```

Note that this method is a class method, signified by the `+` instead of the `-`.  GNUStep implements `new` as follows:

```
+ new
{
   return [[self alloc] init];
}
```

The idiomatic way to use `new` would be:

```
File *obj = [File new];
```

This is in fact what you have done, however, this is calling the class method `new` not your instance method `new`.

If you wanted to call your `new` method you'd have to call:

```
File *obj = [[File alloc] new];
```

but as others have stated you'd need to return your object. Removing your new method would have no effect on your implementation as it isn't currently being called.

Secondly, you have placed your call to `fclose` in your overriden `release` method.  This is wrong, certainly in Apple's implementation of `Object` anyway, GNUstep appears to be different.  `release` could get called multiple times on a single instance of an object.  `retain` and `release` are used to increment/decrement the objects retain count.  Only when the retain count reaches zero should the file handle be closed.  Normally, within Foundation you'd place the call to `fclose` in a `dealloc` method.  `dealloc` is Objective-C's destructor method.  The `dealloc` should look something like:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    fclose(pFile);
    [super dealloc];
}
```

However, `dealloc` doesn't appear to be implemented in either Apple's or GNUstep's `Object` class.  There is, as you point out in your question a `free` method which seems to be a destructor.

It would appear that replacing the above `dealloc` method with an equivalent `free` method would work as a destructor, e.g.:

```
- (void)free
{
    fclose(pFile);
    [super free];
}
```

Apple's implementation of `Object` contains `retain` and `release` methods but the GNUstep implementation does not.  Neither implementation contains a `dealloc` method.

The implementations of `Object.m` and `NSObject.m` for Apple and GNUstep can be found at the following locations:

Apple Object.m: http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532.2/runtime/Object.m

GNUstep Object.m: https://github.com/gnustep/gnustep-libobjc/blob/master/Object.m

Apple NSObject.mm: http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532.2/runtime/NSObject.mm

GNUstep NSObject.m: https://github.com/gnustep/gnustep-base/blob/master/Source/NSObject.m

Comment: I think in newer GNUstep runtime it isn't implementing any Object method.

Comment: @FredFrith-MacDonald That is entirely possible, I have limited experience using GNUstep

Comment: @FredFrith-MacDonald I just had a quick look and `Object.m` is included in `gnustep-objc-1.7.2.tar.gz` which is listed as a prerequisite on the GNUstep website at http://www.gnustep.org/resources/downloads.php

Comment: That one was old runtime. I don't use it though some people are still using it. The newer runtime is at http://svn.gna.org/viewcvs/gnustep/libs/libobjc2/trunk/

Comment: @FredFrith-MacDonald Interesting, I'll have a look at this runtime.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: class_copyMethodList(object_getClass(ObjectClass),) returns NULL. It was only registered for Protocol AFAIK. If you want to use clang and Objective-C 2.0 then this is your runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Is `release` defined on class `Object`?  If it is not, then your call to

```
[super release];
```

will not work.  (In cocoa, release is a member of `NSObject`; your `Object` class may or may not have it, and in fact the retain/release reference counting might not be there at all.)

You should confirm that your base class includes all methods called via `super`.